# Inserting formula results in Run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba script which inserts some formulas. For some reason, it refuses to insert a VLOOKUP function; it gives a Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

My code is as follows:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 16).Formula = "=vlookup(O" & row & ";Sheet2!$A$2:$H$250;5;FALSE)"
```

I've been trying all kinds of variations to figure out what is triggering the error code. If I try the nonsense formula

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 16).Formula = "=vlookp(O1)"
```

It does not generate an error and places the formula in the respective cell. If I change just one letter, by making vlookp(01) into vlookup(01) it generates the error again.

Any idea what is going on and what causes this error?

Txs!!
Bart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `;` as a delimiter for your formula, Excel is very English oriented, and it likes to find `,` in the formula.

So change your formula to:

```
"=vlookup(O" & Row & ",Sheet2!$A$2:$H$250,5,FALSE)"
```

Or change:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 16).Formula
```

to:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 16).FormulaLocal
```

Comment: That explains why I've seen semicolons in formula and what `.Formulalocal`  is for.  Well done

Comment: @ThomasInzina  welcome back, how's the c# coming along ?

Comment: It's not...lol I decided to keep programming a hobby.  Thanks for asking

Answer (score 3):

Replace the semicolons in your formula with commas.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 16).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(O" & Row & ",Sheet2!$A$2:$H$250,5,FALSE)"
```

Comment: for Beating me to it by a few seconds (+1) ; but I had to type a lot more

Answer (score 0):

Not a straight answer, but a way to solve your issue:
enter the formula manually in cell P2 (or any other cell), then press *ctrl+G* to go to the debug window, and type `print range("p2").formula`.
That should give a precise idea of what Excel expects the formula to look like in VBA.